# 125 kHz Arduino RDM6300 read issue

Tags: rfid, wave, waveform

I've tried to read a 125 kHz signal with an Arduino using an RDM6300 module, but it didn't work.

I tried to catch the signal with Audacity. Please find attached photo with the signal.

How can I catch it with Arduino?

[image]

It looks like at the beginning we have tag wake up signal, at the end transmitting data, but what's in the middle of wake-up and data? And how do I read it with Arduino?

Also, I had attached 3 Audacity shots of 125 kHz signal in .waw format.

My Arduino setup:
[image]

Code:

```html
#include <rdm6300.h>

#define RDM6300_RX_PIN 6

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rdm6300.begin(RDM6300_RX_PIN);
  Serial.println("\nPlace RFID tag near the rdm6300...");
}

void loop()
{
  if (rdm6300.update())
    Serial.println(rdm6300.get_tag_id(), HEX);
  delay(10);
}
```

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/150EnCteaAyteGfLEWu-ahQjnc2tMBErx?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also connect the RX pin to the arduino..

Comment: RX pin is connected instead of TX. Wrong picture, sorry.

Comment: 125 kHz signal requires a sampling rate *of at least* 250 kHz. This is well above the audio frequencies that Audacity is meant for. And I doubt that a Nano ADC can run that fast as well. Perhaps you're sample stream doesn't make sense because sampling rate is not high enough.

Comment: Could you recommend how can I record good quality stream? Maybe there some ADC module for Arduino to read that signal correctly?